# Weinberg's Normal Ordering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory

I have the exact same question about Weinberg's volume 1 that was posted in physicsforums.com 10 years ago but it was never answered. I would greatly appreciate it if someone knows whether there is an error or a subtle argument to the following:

> In the lower part of page 200 (around eq. 5.1.35) in his book, Weinberg says that any normal-ordered function of the fields can be expressed as a sum of ordinary products of the fields with c-number coefficients. I don't quite see this. A field can be decomposed in terms of parts that contain either only creation operators or only annihilation operators. $$\phi ( x ) = \phi^ + ( x ) + \phi^ − ( x ) \\
> \phi^† ( x ) = \phi^ + {}^† ( x ) + ϕ^− {}^† ( x )$$
> If we consider a function of fields $F ( \phi ( x ) , \phi^ † ( x ) )$ and its normal ordered version $: F ( \phi ( x ) , \phi^ † ( x ) ) :$ , the difference between the two seems to involve the commutators of all of the following quantities: $\phi^+ ( x ) , \phi^− ( x ) , \phi^+{}^ † ( x ) ,\phi^− {}^† ( x )$. However, Weinberg says that we can express it in terms of only $\phi ( x ) , \phi^ † ( x )$ . Is there any simple argument to justify this? My impression is that Weinberg would provide some arguments in the book unless it is too obvious.

Reference: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-question-about-normal-ordering-regarding-weinbergs-qft-vol-1-p-200.524425/

Comment: Do you want to express the normal ordered function or the difference between the function and its normal ordered form?

Comment: @RogerVadim as far as I understand, Weinberg claims that the difference between the function and its normal ordered form can be written in terms of the fields $\phi,\phi^\dagger$. I can not see why or if this is true.